# Problem with publishing Twist message from a node

Tags: turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a piece of C++ code which should publish twist message and make a fake turtlebot start moving in Rviz. But after running it, the robot had no reaction.Here is my code.

```
#define PI 3.14
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "test");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub=
    n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel",5);
    int rate=50;
ros::Rate loop_rate(rate);

double linear_speed=0.2;
double goal_distance=1.0;
double linear_duration=goal_distance/linear_speed;
double angular_speed=1.0;
double goal_angle=PI;
double angular_duration=goal_angel/angular_speed;
geometry_msgs::Twist twist_msg;
twist_msg.linear.x=twist_msg.linear.y=twist_msg.linear.z=0;
twist_msg.angular.x=twist_msg.angular.y=twist_msg.angular.z=0;

while(ros::ok())
{
    twist_msg.linear.x=linear_speed;
    int ticks=static_cast<int>(linear_duration*rate);
    for(int j=0;j<ticks;j++)
    {
        cmd_vel_pub.publish(twist_msg);
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    twist_msg.linear.x=0;
    cmd_vel_pub.publish(twist_msg);
    ros::Duration(1).sleep();

    twist_msg.angular.z=angular_speed;
    ticks=static_cast<int>(goal_angle*rate);
    for(int j=0;j<ticks;j++)
    {
        cmd_vel_pub.publish(twist_msg);
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    twist_msg.angular.z=0;
    cmd_vel_pub.publish(twist_msg);
    ros::Duration(1).sleep();
    
}

twist_msg.linear.x=0;
twist_msg.angular.z=0;
cmd_vel_pub.publish(twist_msg);
ros::Duration(1).sleep();

return 0;
```

}

I also add the following code in CMakeList.txt

```
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(test src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Add this to package.xml

```
<build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
<run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226391/problem-with-publishing-twist-message-from-a-node/) by [percy_liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25923/percy_liu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem could be because of the incorrect topic name. As far as I remember, the correct topic for moving a turtlebot would be /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop . Try changing cmd_vel to /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop in your code.

---

Originally posted by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) with karma: 206 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [percy_liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25923/percy_liu/) on 2016-02-12**:
There was no error reported when catkin_ws wan running, but no executable file was generated. I don't know how did that happen.

**Comment by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) on 2016-02-12**:
If `talker.cpp` is the name of you cpp file, once you call `catkin_make`, if there is no error, the executable will be generated in `your_workspace/devel/lib`.
BTW you need to add `find_package(geometry_msgs)` in your `CMakeList.txt`

**Comment by [percy_liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25923/percy_liu/) on 2016-02-12**:
I added the sentence as you suggested. And no error reported during `catkin_make`, but still no executable file. Anyway, thanks for your help!

**Comment by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) on 2016-02-12**:
what is the output of `rospack find your_package_name_here` ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First you should monitor the cmd_vel topic from the command line using "rostopic echo /cmd_vel" or using the rqt Topic Monitor plugin. After verifying that no messages are showing up on that topic you can look at the code to see why.

Some new users think that the "cmd_vel_pub.publish(twist_msg)" calls will actually "publish" their data. That call actually queues up the data for publication. You need at least one "ros::spinOnce()" call inside the while loop which will send out the queued messages.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1